# How to inject characters into a string?

Tags: python, string

I have a function in which I need to inject a character before every odd index of a string.

```
def inject(s, i):
sent = str(s)
    new = []
    for w in sent:
        if w == ' ':
          new.append(w)
        elif (sent.index(w) % 2 == 1):
          new.append(str(i) + w)
        else:
          new.append(w)
    return ''.join(new)
```

The function works for:

```
inject(1339, 3)
output: '1333339'
```

and works for

```
inject('This is a test', 'x')
output: 'Txhixs ixs a txexst'
```

but won't work for:

```
inject('Hello World', 'x')
output: 'Hxello World'
```

I know it has something to do with it breaking on the 'll' but can't figure out how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do this:

```py
def inject(s, i):
    sent = str(s)
    new = []
    for idx,w in enumerate(sent):
        if w == ' ':
          new.append(w)
        elif idx % 2 == 1:
          new.append(str(i) + w)
        else:
          new.append(w)
    return ''.join(new)

for t in [1339, 'This is a test', 'Hello World']:
    print(t, inject(t,'x'))
```

When using the `enumerate()` you get the index of each character without having to search for it.

The `sent.index(w)` call just doesn't do what you want it to even though it might seem like it does when there are no repeated characters in a string.

Comment: `sent.index(w)` always returns index of first match.Actually  I think We cant expect it to return what we want, and call it `terribly unreliable` when it doesnt return our expected value.